# Mongo DB $lookup with no common value to match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am a novice to MongoDb and am trying to join two collections where there is no common value.

I have two collections.

```
collection 1 : Role  
Fields : Role, UserName
```

```
collection 2 :mysite  
Fields : userName ,userEmail
```

In collection 1:
eg :

```json
{
'Role' :"admin"
'UserName' : "abc.efg"
}
```

In collection 2:
eg:

```json
{
'userName' : "abc Mr, efg" 
'userEmail' : "abc.efg@company.com"
}
```

The value of username is different in format so I am looking for a way to join these two collections.

Is there any way to merge these two collections please.
Kindly help on this.

Comment: Hey @Adarsh, What are the possible combinations of this. Like ` abc Mr, efg` and  ` abc Mrs, efg` and ` abc Ms, efg`. Are there fixed number of combinations OR it can be any random string?

Comment: It can have Mr,Mrs,Ms as u said. Basically it follows firstname title(Mr or Mrs or Ms),lastname

Comment: Can a user have middle name?

Comment: To be precise,the data is saved as per the email with the title in between. so abc.efg@company.com is the mail id ,then name is abc Mr,efg. Thats how it gets saved so no middle name is required.Thanks for asking and sorry that i missed this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform uncorrelated subqueries between two collections as well as allow other join conditions besides a single equality match, the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage has the following syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
       pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the collection to join> ],
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

You can use the following aggregation query using the above $lookup syntax:

```
db.Role.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "mysite",
      let: {
        "userName": "$UserName"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              "$ne": [
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$userEmail",
                    "$$userName"
                  ]
                },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "mysite"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$mysite"
  },
  
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6HaO-15M8Vs)

[$indexOfCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) searches a string for an occurrence of a substring and returns the index of the first occurrence. If the substring is not found, it returns -1.

So, in the following stage, it checks if `UserName` substring is present in `userEmail`, if not it returns -1, if present it returns the index at which the substring is located.

Hence using the expr `$ne -1` , it matches all documents that have `UserName`substring present in `userEmail`, ignoring the documents where given substring is not present.

```
{
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              "$ne": [
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$userEmail",
                    "$$userName"
                  ]
                },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. it was definitely helpful. If possible could you explain what happens with $ne (also the -1 argument ) please.It would help me and others as well.Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.